# Why am I not able to access phpMyAdmin in wamp server?

Tags: php, mysql

I am not able to access phpMyAdmin. The error is:

> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

I have not set the password. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Maybe you should set the password for the database and in PMA then try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

- [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' with PHPMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482970/1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no)
- http://www.ostraining.com/blog/coding/error-1045-phpmyadmin/

or if you have Skype then try to uninstall and after installing WAMP then reinstall Skype

Answer (score 0):

you can reset your mysql password by this commnand

```
mysqladmin -u root password NEWPASSWORD
```