# Change MySQL root password in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I've setup `wamp` server on window. Then, I use MySQL `root` password by cmd. As a result, when I access phpMyAdmin site, `Access denied` appeared (Default user for phpMyAdmin is `root` and password is `blank/empty`). So, how could I change `config` variables in phpMyAdmin with new password of root.

I've searched for solution on Internet, someone advise me add some line to `config.inc.php` as:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'Changed';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPasswordRoot'] = false;
```

But, It seem not work. Thanks.

Comment: Default username for PHPMyAdmin is root and password blank

Comment: I 've change password of root in mysql. So I need to reconfig phpmyadmin. I don't think use blank pass is a good idea

Comment: what error you get when try to login?

Comment: #1045 - Accès refusé pour l'utilisateur: 'root'@'@localhost' (mot de passe: NON)
I get it. Thanks

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11483057/1501051 and http://stackoverflow.com/a/12525947/1501051

Comment: it could be that new password is not active yet. try FLUSH PRIVILEGES or restart mysql.

Comment: Thanks, I 'll see it right now

Comment: Dear عثمان غني
I did as you refer. It seem to like solution I talk in question. But It's not work. My config.inc.php has no line as it. I add it but not OK.
My phpmyadmin version is 4.1.14. Maybe it is not the same.

Comment: Try http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?540980-1045-Access-denied-for-user-root-localhost-%28using-password-NO%29 and http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,30300,31127 once. Otherwise you should reinstall wamp.

Comment: does it work if you put auth_type to cookie and enter password manually?

Comment: Thanks for all. I've editted correct config file in wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14 and It works. I've editted it in wamp\scripts ,wrong directory, before.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

**Explain what video describe to resolve problem**

After Changing Password of root (Mysql Account). Accessing to phpmyadmin page will be denied because phpMyAdmin use root/''(blank) as default username/password. To resolve this problem, you need to reconfig phpmyadmin. Edit file config.inc.php in folder %wamp%\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14 (Not in %wamp%)

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'changed';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

If you have more than 1 DB server, add "i++" to file and continue add new config as above

Comment: Yes, It works, thank for your help.
I've editted file config but in folder wamp\scripts not wamp\apps\phpmyadmin4.1.14, so stupid :)
Sorry I can't vote you answer up because I don't have privileges enoungh. Newbie I'm

Comment: Someone could vote this answer up. In that video has some other customize config

Comment: +1 as it helps @QuyenLe but it is not a good answer according to SO. There should be no external links in answer.

Comment: @QuyenLe Mark this answer as accepted. Better if you edit this answer and add what you exactly done to help others. thanks

Comment: you can also open an Incognito windows instead of disabling extentions

Answer (score 15):

You can change the mysql root password by logging in to the database directly (mysql -h your_host -u root) then run

```
SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('yourpassword');
```

Comment: Try to understand his problem. He has problem logging into PMA. He already changed the password.

Comment: Yes, as عثمان غني said

Comment: This helped me nonetheless workaround a problem where I needed to reset the password for a user, not root, in MySQL DB used by WordPress on an ISP.  I used the command to reset the password (for userxyz instead of root) within php-MyAdmin using SQL window. Then I changed the webroot/wp-config.php file to update the password in that file.  I tested and all worked fine.  Note that upon changing the password the PMA session ended and I had to login again with the new password. Then I modified wp-config.php. Then tested.

Answer (score 7):

0) go to phpmyadmin don't select any db
1) Click "Privileges". You'll see all the users on MySQL's privilege tables.
2) Check the user "root" whose Host value is localhost, and click the "Edit Privileges" icon.
3) In the "Change password" field, click "Password" and enter a new password.
4) Retype the password to confirm. Then click "Go" to apply the settings.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this command

```
 mysql> UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('Your new Password') WHERE User='root';
```

check the links
 http://www.kirupa.com/forum/showthread.php?279644-How-to-reset-password-in-WAMP-server
 http://www.phpmytutor.com/blogs/2012/08/27/change-mysql-root-password-in-wamp-server/

Find your config.inc.php file under the phpMyAdmin installation directory and update the line that looks like
   this:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'password';
```

... to this:

```
 $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'newpassword';
```

Comment: Thank but maybe I talk my trouble not clearly enoungh. I can change password of root as you said. But, what I need is reconfig phpmyadmin to use new user/password. To avoid access denied. Sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Change It like this, It worked for me. Hope It helps.
firs I did

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'changed';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Then I Changed Like this...

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['verbose'] = 'mysql wampserver';
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'root';
/* Server parameters */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['compress'] = false;
/* Select mysql if your server does not have mysqli */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['extension'] = 'mysqli';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do 2 steps:

- follow `Tiep Phan` solution ... edit `config.inc.php` file ...
- follow `Mahmoud Zalt` solution ... change password within phpmyadmin