# I am getting error while trying to connect to localhost phpmyadmin

Tags: java, php, android, mysql

I am new to the php server side and with  mysql.With having some basic knowledge about that all.Recently install wamp server and some php file and database creation i m trying to connect my android app to the localhost running mysql database (as you might be knowing like some webservice).

So in the browser i typed `http://localhost` in the url address space and its shows the wampserver home page

but when i typed `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` its shows some error page I am attaching the screenshot for the error page

Here is the screen

[image: phpmyadmin showing error page]

So anybody can tell me what should I do in order to get the correct phpmyadmin page.
If more info require in this part pls let me know

Comment: maybe this answer will help [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482970/1045-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-using-password-no)

Answer (score 1):

First stop Mysql:

## Sudo / etc / init.d / mysql stop

Then open the configuration file php5 and look for the line that enables entry into Safe Mode:

## Vim / etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

Within vim enter the functions mode / safe (to locate the line) and change it to On

safe_mode = Onn

Exit VIM editor and save the changes:

Restart the MySQL mode security (safe_mod):

## Safe_mysqld-skip-grant-tables &

With MySQL in safe mode select the mysql table and then change the root password and grant all privileges and exit MySQL with the EXIT command.

Mysql> USE mysql

mysql> UPDATE user SET password = password ("new_password") WHERE user = "root";

Result: 
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec) 
Rows matched: 3 Changed: 1 Warnings: 0

mysql> flush privileges;

Result: 
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> exit

Now the Linux Shell kill all mysql processes

## Killall mysqld mysql

Mysql restart normally.

## / etc / init.d / mysql start

To test access MySQL from the terminal and the browser through PhpMyAdmin 
Terminal:

## mysql-u root-p

```
http://localhost/phpmyadmin
```

Enter username and password for root.

Comment: Did you take a look at the screenshot? OP is using windows 8, not Linux

Comment: Sorry. My bad. But the solution is to change the Username and pass. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure you started Your server
2. go to server and start it
3. then enter localhost/phpmyadmin
4. find your database then select you database

Answer (score 0):

You have to allow localhost access to your mysql server. And its basicly the same question as https://superuser.com/questions/603026/mysql-how-to-fix-access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reset the password.

First start the mysql server instance or daemon with the --skip-grant-tables option. (security setting)

Then Execute these statements.

```
# mysql -u root mysql 
mysql> UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('your_new_password') where USER='root'; 
mysql> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Finally, restart the instance/daemon without the --skip-grant-tables option.

You should be able to connect with your new password.

```
# mysql -u root -p 
Enter password: your_new_password
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to change the password of the user root and then modify the file `config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you installed the wamp server directly onto your (C:) drive and not into program files -

Secondly, you need to actually run the server to access localhost - you can do this by opening up the control panel for the server and starting the APACHE and MYSQL services.