# How to update PHP version in Current Wampserver

Tags: php, wampserver

I'm using windows 7 32bit. My current PHP version is `5.3.5` i want to make it `5.5` and further newer version. I searched on google but  couldn't find.My phpmyAdmin look like this [image: image of phpmyadmin]  Kindly Help me Solve This and Suggest me with Method and Steps.  Thanks in Advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' with PHPMyAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482970/access-denied-for-user-rootlocalhost-with-phpmyadmin)

Answer (score 0):

1. Download latest portable version of XAMPP.
2. Extract the archive(not where XAMPP already installed).
3. Copy the PHP folder from the extracted archive.
4. Keep back up of PHP folder which is in installed XAMPP directory. You can backup it like changing the PHP folder name to PHP-old or like PHP-version-number
5. Paste the PHP folder which you copied from the extracted archive.
6. Replace the php.ini file with your backup folder php.ini file in case you have changed the default settings earlier.
7. That's all, start/restart the server.

Comment: not working mine is  wampserver and my pc  Compiler is MSVC6 (Visual C++ 6.0)